# cURL post method not creating cookie

Tags: php, curl

In the below code i am trying to post the username and password but not able to create the cookie using post, if i do the same with get method it creates the cookie.

```
    $BASEURL="http://localhost/openx/www/api/json/index.php/main/authenticate/";

    $POSTFIELDS='username="'.$username.'"&password="'.$password.'"';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $BASEURL);


    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
```

The curl_getinfo($ch) returns 200 OK http code, can anybody please advice what is wrong with the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to close the connection for cookiejar because as per the docs the jar file is the name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookiejar is only saved when you close the curl handle using curl_close($ch).

From the manual:

**CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**
The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

**CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**
The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I have used curl_close($ch) at the end of all the statement but still it is not able to write into file. please advice

Comment: do you have write access to the directory you are trying to save the file?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code to below and now working for me.

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp/", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $BASEURL='http://localhost/openx/www/api/json/index.php/main/authenticate/';
        $POSTFIELDS='username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/openx/www/api/json/index.php/main/authenticate/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS);

        ob_start();      // prevent any output
        $result=curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
        ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```